# Placing Pivot Table in Added Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have vba code that pulls data and then created a pivot table from the data. What is happening now is that every time I hit the button to create the pivot table it gets put into a new sheet with a different number. What I want to happen is the pivot table put in the new sheet I have created. I have added the code I have written below. Thanks in advance.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set pc = src.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
wsNew.Name = "DAM-AWW Pivot"

Set objtable = ws.PivotTableWizard(, , , , False)
objtable.Name = "DAM-AWW Pivot"
```

Answer (score 0):

When I create PivotTables using VBA, I'm not using the wizard. I've found it to be more flexible to put the PT exactly where I want it with two steps: creating the `PivotCache` then creating the `PivotTable`.

Below is a cut/paste of function I use all the time to either update or create a new `PivotTable`:

```vb
Private Sub UpdatePivotTable(ptwb As Workbook, ptName As String, ptRange As Range)
    On Error GoTo Err_UpdatePivotTable

    '--- refreshes the data in the given pivot table for the (potentially)
    '    expanded data range; creates the pivot table if it doesn't exist
    Dim thisPivot As PivotTable
    Dim ptCache As PivotCache
    Dim ptSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ptField As PivotField
    Dim ptshname As String

    '--- make sure the destination workbook and sheet are correctly
    '    set up and ready
    ptshname = ptName & " Pivot"
    Set ptSheet = ptwb.Sheets(ptshname)

    '--- does the pivot table even exist?
    On Error Resume Next
    Set thisPivot = ptSheet.PivotTables(ptName)
    On Error GoTo Err_UpdatePivotTable

    If thisPivot Is Nothing Then
        Set ptCache = ptwb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                              SourceData:=ptRange, _
                                              version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)
        Set thisPivot = ptCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ptSheet.Range("B9"), _
                                                 TableName:=ptName, _
                                                 DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12)
        With thisPivot
            Set ptField = .PivotFields("ProjectID")
            ptField.Orientation = xlRowField
            ptField.Position = 1
            Set ptField = .PivotFields("ProjectName")
            ptField.Orientation = xlRowField
            ptField.Position = 2
            Set ptField = .PivotFields("LaborMonth")
            ptField.Orientation = xlColumnField
            ptField.Position = 1
            Set ptField = .AddDataField(.PivotFields("Hours"), "Sum of Hours", xlSum)
            .InGridDropZones = True
            .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
            For Each ptField In .PivotFields
                ptField.Subtotals(1) = True
                ptField.Subtotals(1) = False
            Next ptField
            .DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "0.00;;-"
            .DataBodyRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .ColumnRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"
        End With
    Else
        thisPivot.ChangePivotCache ptwb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                                           SourceData:=ptRange, _
                                                           version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)
        thisPivot.PivotCache.Refresh
    End If
    thisPivot.PivotFields("LaborMonth").AutoSort xlAscending, "LaborMonth"

Exit_UpdatePivotTable:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Err_UpdatePivotTable:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & _
           ") in procedure UpdatePivotTable of " & _
           "Module CostpointLabor", vbOKOnly
    Resume Exit_UpdatePivotTable
End Sub
```

Clearly most of this is an example to use to tailor to your specific needs.

Comment: I'm kind of a new kid on the block when it comes to coding I dont really understand all what is encompassed in your code.. I currently have my code in a public sub because I am pulling and manipulating data before I make the pivot.. should I just make the private sub and then call it in the public sub after the data has been changed?

Comment: Sorry if that was a confusing point. In order to give an answer in the few minutes I had available, I cut/pasted an existing function that happens to be Private. For you, replace the two lines starting with `Set objtable = ws.PivotTableWizard...` and replace it with one line `Set objtable = pc.CreatePivotTable(wsNew.Range("A10"), "DAM-AWW Pivot")`. See where that leaves things.

Comment: I tried that and no pivot table is being made lol... the new sheet appears but nothing happens